# List the Facebook comments that I liked all the time

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-like

How can I see all the comments I liked on Facebook?

I looked on the Activity log< pages, but I didn't find something useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your Activity Log.

Click "Likes" to open a sub-menu.

There are a couple of options there, including "Pages and Interests" and what you want: "Posts and Comments".

[image: Activity Log "Likes" menu]

Comment: Does this work for you? That's the expected way, but I cannot see  the comments I liked. I tested it right now: I liked a comment, and refreshed "Posts and Comments" page. The comment I liked is not listed there... Maybe a bug?

Comment: Works for me. Perhaps there's some caching?

Comment: Tried without cache, too. I accepted this answer since this is supposed to work. I will try to get them via Facebook APIs and if it fails, I will report it as bug against Facebook likes. Thanks!